# Paragraph level spans

Tags: android

I am trying to apply a rounded background span with padding to a paragraph within a Spannable. I have tried using LeadingMarginSpan, ReplacementSpan and LineBackgroundSpan. These all seem to operate on a per line basis, which causes rounded background on each line in the paragraph or don't apply padding correctly. Being able to know the line number during the span draw() would allow me to square of the bottom of the text, but this doesn't seem available.

Is it possible to achieve this styling with the Android framework? note all the text here is part of the Spannable.

[image]